# If $FX_t=X_{t+1}$ and $BX_t=X_{t-1}$ show that $F=B^{-1}$ and $B=F^{-1}$

Tags: regression, time-series, self-study, lags

So the backshift operator is defined as: 
$$BX_t=X_{t-1}$$
And the forward shift operator is defined as:
$$FX_t=X_{t+1}$$
Can someone please help show me how $F=B^{-1}$ and $B=F^{-1}$ are true?

My attempt
$$FX_t=X_{t+1}$$
so
$$F^{-1}X_t=X_{t-1}=BX_t$$
and
$$BX_t=X_{t-1}$$
so
$$B^{-1}X_t=X_{t+1}=FX_t$$

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thank you.  So when you apply $FB$ you are first subtracting $1$ and then adding $1$ to the indexes.  How does the result compare to what you started with?  Repeat this reasoning for $BF$ and you will be done.

Comment: Are $X_t$ and $X_{t+1}$ and $X_{t-1}$ _vectors_ or scalars? If the former, you cannot write things like $F = \frac{X_{t+1}}{X_t}$: division of vectors is not defined. If they are scalars, then surely the commutative law of multiplication of real numbers (namely, $a* b = b*a$) allows you to assert that $X_{t-1}*X_{t+1} = X_{t+1}*X_{t-1}$??

Comment: I would advise you start by defining precisely what $F^{-1}$ means.  Any ideas there?

Comment: They're vectors so i need to treat them like i would a matrix @DilipSarwate

Comment: Then perhaps you can tell us how one vector is divided by another.

Comment: Just erase all the appearances of "$X$" in the question.  It would then ask something like this: "Let $F$ send each index $t$ to $t-1$ and $B$ send each index $t$ to $t+1$. How can I show that the operations $F$ and $B$ undo each other?"  In fact, you can even erase all the appearances of "$t$", after which your question would read: "how can I show that $-1$ is the the negative of $1$ and that $1$ is the negative of $-1$?"

Comment: @whuber I have posted what i believe is the answer. Am i correct? Or should show more?